# JS filtering dates

Tags: javascript

How can I return return all items that have a start date that begins in this year (2018)? This is the same as excluding all items which have a start date > next year (i.e. 2019).

urlArray returns each date format as so:

```
1/1/1970
```

whereas in browser tools the API returns a date format of:

```
"2018-12-26T08:00:00Z"
```

I have tried returning all items with a filter that have a start date less than next year but still not working. My attempt is below:

```
let filteredAZLista = urlArray.filter(c =>  c.StartDate < nextYear);
```

My array:

```
urlArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){

              return {

               StartDate:                        new Date(item.Start_x0020_Date).toLocaleDateString("en-GB"),                      

               EndDate:                          new Date(item.End_x0020_Date).toLocaleDateString("en-GB"),                                

                };  

          });



var nextYear   = '01/01/2019';
```

Comment: Just make `var nextYear = new Date("01/01/2019")` as well and it should work